# How do i identify the 1st, 2nd and 3rd textboxes without using indexes(ex [1]) - xpath, selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, web, input, dynamic

Below is the code. can someone pls help me to identify 3 text boxes individually, without using indexes.

```
 <html>
   <head>
      <title>test</title>
      <script></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      name:
      <input type="text"/>
      <br/>
      name:
      <input type="text"/>
      <br/>
      name:
      <input type="text"/>
      <div>testdiv</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your all 3 elements are identical So it only possible using index like `//input[1]` indirectly if you can use function like `//input[last()]` - it will locate last input tag,  `//input[last()-1]` - it will locate second last input tag or something using `position()` - `//input[position()=1]`  and so on

Comment: What is your business requirement? Why do you want to avoid index?

Comment: Show how you tried to solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try below expressions to match each `input`:

For the first one:

```
//input[not(preceding-sibling::input)]
```

For second:

```
//input[preceding-sibling::input and following-sibling::input]
```

For third:

```
//input[not(following-sibling::input)]
```